# Mint boot error (ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip)

Tags: linux-mint, boot

I was using Linux for a days. I turn on my laptop few minutes ago. Then, I was trying to open Unity. Unfortunately, I was getting lot of errors like I am unable to get things from assets or some other location. Then, I was trying to capture screenshot. Then, I got another error it was "try to save screenshot in another location". I opened *Files* than I got another error again I don't remember what was that. There's a function called *Fix-now* and *Dismiss*. I clicked on *Fix-now* few times but, I was unable to fix that error so, I clicked dismiss. Then, I reboot my laptop. Now, I am completely unable to open my desktop.

Error capture-shot :

[image]

Transcript:

> ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the issue.

```
blkid
```

I wrote above code to get datas of my partitions.

```
fsck /dev/sda5 -y
```

Above code worked for check error and fix. `sda5` was swap partition. It hadn't no error. So, I wrote again

```
fsck /dev/sda6 -y
```

`sda6` was ext4 partition. Then, problem fixed.

You might have same issue as mine. You have check all your partitions(linux folders). Than, your problem will be fixed. Then, you can reboot by following code

```
reboot
```

But, it didn't work for me. So, I just clicked on power off button. Then, I turn my laptop on.

Problem fixed...