# mint boot error multiple times

Tags: linux-mint, boot, error-handling

I earlier was having an [issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/634942/mint-boot-error-ima-error-communicating-to-tpm-chip). I had solved that also. But, I am facing it again. Same issue. Same error. It's been three times I have faced the issue. I had solved the issue same way every time. But, if it always happens than it totally irritating.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that happens that too often, it may mean that your hard drive is faulty. You can check your hard drive status through S.M.A.R.T. data with `gnome-disks` ("three dots menu"/"hamburger" menu) and watch for any errors count or anything related to sectors.

Faulty RAM may also cause such issues, as well as damaged solders (CPU, chipset, motherboard, etc) if your PC stayed too hot (e.g CPU over 70C, etc) for long enough.

Comment: Yes! My PC become hot too fast. I added a picture of information

Comment: Thats not unusual, 12.5" laptops easily heats up even with low power CPUs (we're talking about 1.3Ghz CPUs...) alone, and having a 3.2Ghz one like yours won't really help at all while they are known to even easily heat up normal-sized 15" laptops.
But Thinkpads are mostly reliable latptops but yours, while you have the perfect amount of RAM for such CPU (6GB) and being still perfectly fine for anything besides gaming and intensive loads, is fairly old (almots 10 years now). If I were you, I would really check the hard drive status with `gnome-disks` and see if something is wrong.

Comment: I added a picture of `gnome-disks`

Comment: You have to click on the "three dots" menu, then go to `SMART Data & Self-Tests, then maximize that window and take a screenshot of the whole thing.

Comment: I have added. that screenshot

Comment: So, I have to do now?

Comment: Yeah that's it, your hard drive is dying: Way too much Read Error Rate, Start/Stop Count is on the line of seemingly 9 years of use, Load/Unload Cycle Count is really huge (300 000 is already too much), temperature is 5C more than it should but that's okayish, Reallocation Count is big (it detected 69 errors and somewhat managed to fix it, but that's an early sign of failure). Plus you have Current Pending Sector Count (waiting to be reallocated, confirms it's dying) but UDMA CRC Error Rate is okay. Well, it's time to either ditch the drive, or only use it for data you don't really care about.

Comment: Once you've replaced the drive and only if errors occurs in the future, there would be a high chance that your next point of failure is RAM dying (symptoms: not being able to boot properly, graphical glitches, random crashes, etc). But you've managed to boot properly and recover from this hard drive issue until now, so you are mostly fine for the time being. Just remember what your next culprit would be, just in case.

Comment: I notice that I am getting that error when I run Unity.

Comment: Replace your hard drive first, then reinstall everything and we'll see if this keeps up.